# Node js NAT traversal

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

I going to use **Apache** with **PHP** and **Node.js** on my server. How can I send data to machine, that connected to my server via **tcp socket** if that machine is over the **NAT**? There is a way to do it using php or node.js with sockets?

Comment: Configure port forwarding on the router doing the NAT.

Comment: @Brad, I need do it without port forwarding.

Comment: One way or another, you're going to need to configure that router to send traffic to your server behind it.  Why do you need to do it without port forwarding?  Have you looked into UPnP?

Comment: @Brad, because my machine will be change its location.

Comment: Can you elaborate at all?  Do you mean you're changing its network address?  Or are you physically moving it to some other network?  And, why not configure the router wherever you are.  You need to add many more details to your question, and explain why your situation is different from all the others.  Otherwise, you won't get a very good answer.